# Implementing counters from JSON values

Tags: javascript

I am writing a cloud function which receives the following json

```
{
    "data":{
        "preference1" : "Food",
        "preference2" : "Travel",
        "preference3" : "Fashion"
}
```

The user picks it's top 3 preferences from a list of 10 preferences, i want to implement counters so i can track which are the most picked.

I was thinking of implementing counters in such a way that i would declare the variable and then do a series of if statements to add + 1 if it matches the string.

```
var food = 0 
var travel = 0 
var fashion = 0 
if (data.preference1 == 'Food') { 
  var food = 1 
}
if (data.preference1 == 'Travel') { 
  var travel = 1 
}
```

... and so on.

to ultimately do...

```
countDoc.ref.update({
  food_count: countDoc.ref.data().food_count + food,
  travel_count: countDoc.ref.data().travel_count + travel,
  fashion_count: countDoc.ref.data().fashion_count + fashion
})
```

This would get me the desired result but I know there has to be a cleaner way of doing this. I don't know exactly how to search for this issue or which approach to try.

If i could be pointed in the right direction it would be nice.

Thanks.

Comment: `data` is just one object?

Comment: so basically what you want is: one drop down, and based on selection of the drop down, you want to maintain the json, am i understanding it right or wrong !!!!! :)

Comment: Instead of `var food = 1`, do `food++`.

Comment: @DupinderSingh I guess my ultimate goal is to just read preference1, 2 & 3 and just  find out which of the 10 possible strings it is so i can add +1 to their respective counters. In this example Food, Travel and Fashion would all get a +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use a map:

```
const map = new Map()

// For each data item
Object.values(data).forEach((preference) => {
  const count = (map.get(preference) || 0) + 1
  map.set(preference, count)
})
```

Assuming you have an array of data items:

```
const items = [
  {
    preference1: 'Food',
    preference2: 'Travel',
    preference3: 'Fashion',
  },
  {
    preference1: 'Something',
    preference2: 'Travel',
    preference3: 'Fashion',
  },
  {
    preference1: 'Food',
    preference2: 'Something Else',
    preference3: 'Fashion',
  },
]

const map = new Map()

// For each data item
items.forEach((item) => {
  Object.values(item).forEach((preference) => {
    const count = (map.get(preference) || 0) + 1
    map.set(preference, count)
  })
})

console.log(map)
```

Output:

```
Map {
  'Food' => 2,
  'Travel' => 2,
  'Fashion' => 3,
  'Something' => 1,
  'Something Else' => 1 }
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, that is an invalid JSON - the trailing comma (the one after "Fashion", where there's no further elements) is illegal in JSON. Assuming that's fixed...

While there may be valid reasons why that is the form of the JSON, most people would likely prefer it in this form:

```
{ "data": { "preferences": ["Food", "Travel", "Fashion"] } }
```

with an array instead of an object containing indices within its keys. But assuming you have what you said...

```
// initialise the counter
const counter = {};

// count the data
Object.values(data).forEach(
  pref => counter[pref] ? counter[pref]++ : counter[pref] = 1
);
```

Here, `counter["Food"]` etc will contain the correct counts.

Answer (score 0):

If I was looking for the top three of something I would do something like:

```js
function Counter(title, start){
  this.title = title; this.count = start || 0;
  this.add = function(){
    this.count++;
    return this;
  }
  this.sub = function(){
    this.count--;
    return this;
  }
}
var pants = new Counter('pants'), people = new Counter('people'), boxes = new Counter('boxes'), shirts = new Counter('shirts'), food = new Counter('food'), trees = new Counter('trees'), water = new Counter('water'), rain = new Counter('rain'), sun = new Counter('sun'), animals = new Counter('animals'), shelter = new Counter('shelter');
pants.add().add().add(); people.add(); boxes.add().add(); shirts.add().add().add(); food.add().add().add().add().add(); trees.add().add(); water.add().add().add().add().add(); rain.add().add(); sun.add(); animals.add(); shelter.add().add().add().add().add();
var counts = [pants, people, boxes, shirts, food, trees, water, rain, sun, animals, shelter];
counts.sort(function(a, b){
  return b.count-a.count;
});
var topThree = counts.slice(0, 3);
topThree.forEach(function(o){
  console.log(o.title);
});
```

Note that you can dynamically, `counterInstance.add()` onclick on the DOM, to achieve the desired result.